# Filled Form is not rendered

Tags: java, forms, playframework, playframework-2.3

In my app a user is filling out a form with his information (program of study, credits earned, gender, age, etc.). Play validates the data (e.g. depending on the program of study there is an upper bound for credits earned) and upon an error returns a badRequest() with a form filled with the provided data.

The problem is, the filled form is not rendered.

Controller code:

```
Form<UserData> bound = form(UserData.class).bindFromRequest();
    if (bound.hasErrors()){
        //retrieve data from form
        Map<String, String> map = bound.data();
        //build a new UserData object, filled with the submitted values
        UserData data = new UserData(map);
        //fill new Form instance with object
        Form<UserData> dataForm = form(UserData.class).fill(data);
        flash("error", "Form has errors!");
        return badRequest(
                userDataForm.render(dataForm)
        );
```

My template looks like this:

```
<fieldset>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @bootstrap.select(userDataForm("program"),
                        optionList = models.survey.user.StudyProgram.getNameList,
                        label = "Program of Study",
                        help ="Chose the program of study you are currently enrolled in")
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @bootstrap.text(userDataForm("age"),
                        label = "Age",
                        help = "Chose your age",
                        placeholder = "Age"
                    )
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @bootstrap.select(userDataForm("gender"),
                        optionList = scala.List("Female","Male"),
                        label = "Gender",
                        help ="Chose the gender you identify with")
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    @bootstrap.text(userDataForm("credits"),
                        label = "How many credits (Leistungspunkte) have you earned so far (maximum: 180 for B.Sc., 120 for M.Sc.)?",
                        help = "How many credits have you earned so far?",
                        placeholder = "Credits"
                    )
                </div>
```

Why is the filled Form not rendered? All I see is an empty form-page as if no values were entered. I can see that the partial Object has all the values I want it to have.

I also tried to make a value-HashMap and bind the filled Form from that:

```
Map<String, String> map = bound.data();
Form<UserData> form = form(UserData.class).bind(map, "program", "age", "gender", "credits");
```

Comment: In the Controller, you don't need to create a new Form instance. You can reuse "bound" and render it again

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. It's also the way it's done in the documentation but still it rendered an empty form.

Comment: Try to debug the errors after binding, maybe they come from somewhere else, or your initial binding did not work.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I finally resolved this issue: the problem was my template. My scala.html files just didn't behave like the original bootstrap 3 ones, so I switched them out and, voila, it works like a charm again.